# Hot Swap Controller what could've gone wrong

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, failure-analysis

Back at it again, now with four hot-swap controller implementations that somehow broke down. I've got four of the circuits pointed out below on a PCB next to each other. All four circuits are powered by a 48V source. These circuits make use of:

- CSD19536KTT 100V n-channel MOSFET
- TPS2490 hot-swap controller

The circuit is there to provide a slow start to a motor controller (and motor) to prevent a FET breakdown. The enable-pin on the hot-swap controllers are driven by a microcontroller that supplies 5V when 'high'.

During testing the hot-swap on the first of the four loads, the fourth circuit sparked and the MOSFET broke down. Now, this fourth circuit is having 48V on both source, drain and the gate of the FET and this led to a broken hot-swap controller as well. Also, on the first circuit, the gate-ground voltage is now somehow 62?!? volts. In the meanwhile, the 2nd and 3rd will no longer give a voltage other than a couple of milli-volts even while the enable signal is 5V.

To refer to the schematic, the fourth circuit has visible damage between the Vcc and Vsense pins of U1.

On each load's ground, there is a current sensor we use but I'm not feeling this has anything to do with it.

As I've not exactly stated a question, it would be: except for the measurements we've already done (measuring the voltages at points), what might we look into to figure out the cause of this issue we're finding ourselves in? Is there anything we might be missing here and if so, could one explain a bit the details of such a problem?

Datasheets:

MOSFET: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd19536ktt.pdf?ts=1619099126555

Hot-Swap controller: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2490.pdf?ts=1619078176827

[image: Schematics]

---

Edit:

I added two images of my routing. 1 with the polygons and one without. Note that I wrote (great paint skills) +48V on the top polygon which is the high-current path and one with GND on the bottom. Also note the via's in the bottom polygon connecting to a full GND layer.

[image: Layout with polygons]
[image: Layout without polygons]

Comment: I'd suggest you look carefully at the pcb layout. Are the high current tracks low inductance? Have you taken into account where the current is flowing and ensuring the low current control circuitry is out of the high current paths?

Comment: All high-current paths are whole polygons and with 'out of the high current paths' I'm not quite sure what you mean. I mean, they are sort of separated but could you elaborate a bit on specifically what you mean?

Comment: you might want to show us a picture of the pcb layout. Then we can refer to specific instances. If you have significant current flowing through your 0V track and there is your control circuitry connected at various points along that track - due to voltage drops, the control circuit may see different voltages on the 0V track. This is why you need to understand where the current is flowing.

Comment: I did my best to create a clear layout for you. Added in the edit

Comment: The wiring on the sense resistor requires a 4 wire kelvin connection. D1 seems a bit small to do anything useful. You probably want a varistor across the output.

Comment: Hmm that might be a good tip though haha. But could this actually lead to a breakdown as described?

Comment: I’d suggest you do initial tests using a resistive load. For the motor/driver, I’d be adding a varistor to clamp any inductive kickback. I’d also suggest you identify what components were damaged in your initial tests.

Comment: I already performed the test with a resistive load this was also the moment when the hot swap controller broke down. Some other test concluded that 3 of the four hot swap controller are broken en that one of the Mosfets is broken. You're previous comment about the needed kelvin connection was indeed correct. However, I fail to see how this could be the reason why the hot swap controller broke down. Could you explain that in some more detail?

Comment: It is one of probably a number of issues. You’ll need to perform tests and identify what causes the failure. The first thing is to ensure it works on paper - ie do calcs etc.